# Can barley flour be used as a substitute for barley malt extract?

Tags: baking, substitutions, bread

A bread recipe is calling for barley malt extract and i dont have it.So can barley flour be used.

Comment: If the bread recipe is calling for barley malt extract for its enzymes, it can probably be left out as flour millers will have included enough amylose enzyme in their flour. To much enzyme activity can leave your baked bread gummy. Millers have the equipment and expertise to adjust their products for good performance.

Answer (score 5):

No, they are quite different. Barley flour is just the milled grain, but malt has been sprouted so it has much higher enzymatic activity and is much sweeter. It is usually used to precipitate an enzymatic reaction in your bread, which plain barley flour won't do. The recipe may work by just leaving the malt extract out, but it may brown less or rise more slowly.

Comment: okay.. so any other substitutes like honey or brown sugar???

Comment: There are different kinds of malt, so it's hard to say for sure. Sugar would replace some of the attributes but lack the enzymes. It would help if you could post the recipe.

Comment: Diastatic malt has active enzymes that help break down starches. Non-diastatic malt is used if you want just the sweetening and coloring.